# Splat a Certain Attribute from a List of Objects

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to pass an attribute of each object from a list of objects as arguments to a function.

I know I can pass the objects themselves with `*list`. I want to know if there is a convenient way to pass a certain attribute from the objects with something like `(*list).attribute`.

```py
class Cls():
  def __init__(self, value = 0):
    self.value = value

def func(arg1, arg2, arg3):
  # do something with args
  print(arg1, arg2, arg3)

cls1 = Cls(1)
cls2 = Cls(2)
cls3 = Cls(3)

clsList = [cls1, cls2, cls3]

# is there something short like this?
func((*clsList).value)

# I know I could do something like this
func(*[c.value for c in clsList])
# but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid having the intermediate list
```

Comment: You can use `map()`: `func(*map(lambda i: i.value, clsList))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid the intermediate list using a generator expression:

```
func(*(c.value for c in clsList))
```

Notice that `[x for x in 'abc']` is a list, which is evaluated straight away, while `(x for x in 'abc')` (with parentheses instead of brackets) is a generator, which *is not* fully evaluated at definition, so only a small intermediate object will be created, instead of a possibly huge list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
import operator
func(*map(operator.attrgetter('value'), clsList))
```

since after `f = operator.attrgetter('value')`, the call `f(c)` returns `c.value`. `map` applies `f` to every item in `clsList`, and then `func(*map(...))` passes the unpacked map values as arguments to `func`.